# Tmux window indicator rendering issue with FiraCode Nerd font in Windows Terminal

Tags: tmux, windows-terminal, visual-artifacts

#### Description:

I'm encountering a rendering issue with the [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) window indicator when using the catppuccin theme in combination with the FiraCode Nerd font on [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) within [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux). Specifically, there seems to be a disconnect between the separator and the window number, resulting in a visual artifact.

#### Steps I've Taken:

1. Set up Windows Terminal with WSL.
2. Applied the catppuccin theme for tmux.
3. Set the font to "FiraCode Nerd".
4. Opened multiple tmux windows.

#### Expected Behavior:

The tmux window indicator should render correctly with no visual artifacts, and there should be no disconnect between the separator and the window number.

#### Actual Behavior:

There is a noticeable disconnect between the separator and the window number, resulting in a visual artifact.

#### Additional Information:

- This issue appeared suddenly without any changes to my configuration.
- I've tried troubleshooting by adjusting font sizes, checking for updates, and reviewing configuration settings, but the issue persists.
- Changing fonts did not resolve the issue, suggesting it may not be specific to the FiraCode Nerd font.
- I've attached screenshots for reference.

#### Environment:

- **Operating System:** Windows with WSL
- **Terminal Emulator:** Windows Terminal
- **tmux Version:** Tmux 3.4
- **catppuccin Version:** Updated to the last available using tpm
- **Font:** FiraCode Nerd

#### Screenshots:

[image: A few days ago]

[image: Now]

[image: The issue]

How can I identify the cause of this issue and any potential solutions?

Comment: A good, well-researched question, but since it's not *"unique to programming"*, I've voted to have this moved to Super User where it can hopefully get an answer.  Side-note:  Please by careful with AI use.  It looks like you *may* have used ChatGPT or another LLM to help you word your question, but I can't say for sure. If so, keep in mind that this *technically* isn't allowed here.

Comment: Also note that you can use the same login you have on Stack Overflow here to get access to your question, edit, and reply.  Thanks!

Comment: What is "FiraCode Nerd font"? [A combination](https://github.com/Trzcin/Fira-Code-Nerd) of the [Fira Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fira_(typeface)#Fira_Code) font and [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/#features)?